# How to set up squid_session with transparent proxy

Tags: linux, networking, squid, ubuntu-10.10

I want to set up a transparent squid proxy to monitor the same box it is running on. It needs to use squid_session to first force a login screen to the user, and then allow web browsing until an idle timeout. This is on Ubuntu 10.10, with squid 2.7. I'd like to use squid3 but I'm not sure it is well supported. A link to a tutorial for something like this would also be helpful, as I have not found anything very helpful. 
Edit: my setup is: squid installed on computer A squid is a transparent proxy for computer A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward all your traffic from eth0 to eth1 ( eth0-internal lan interface, eth1-external lan interface ).
Need to create an acl for toimestamping the web access.

Comment: This does not answer the question, I want monitor computer that squid is installed on eg: squid is installed on comp A squid is a transparent proxy for comp A

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that IP for computer A is 192.168.0.1.

Run:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:3128
```

Then:

```
service iptables save
```

To save settings.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `squid_session`, see manual page (`man squid_session`). This is a working example with squid 2.7 in a Debian Server:

```
external_acl_type session ttl=3600 negative_ttl=0 children=1 concurrency=200 %SRC /usr/lib/squid/squid_session -t 3600
acl session external session
acl splash dstdomain example.net
http_access deny !session !splash
deny_info http://example.net/splash?url=%s session
```